# Need help in jQuery AJAX PHP in charactercount

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, keyboard-events

I have a problem with my character count script that is in an input box. When it reaches its maximum level then I call a ajax function it works the first time, but when I type second time in this input box then ajax call and keyup event not working my code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid hide payment_mode_card">
 <input type="text" name="card_number" id="card_number" alt="cc" placeholder="Credit card number" class="required number xlarge span12" />
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var xTriggered = 0;
$('#card_number').live('keyup',function(event) {
if (event.which == 6) {
event.preventDefault();
}
xTriggered++;

if(xTriggered == 6){
var action = "chkcard";
var cardNum = $("#card_number").val();
//alert(cardNum);
$.ajax({ 
        url: "/{$current_folder}/check_card_type.{$CONFIG.site.file.extension}",
        type: "post",
        data: { "cardNum" : cardNum, "action":action},
        success: function(debit_or_credit){
            var dataObj = JSON.parse(debit_or_credit);
            alert('This is a '+dataObj.debit_or_credit+' Card of '+dataObj.card_type+' type');

        },
        error: function(){
            alert('There is an error');
        }
    });
  }
})
```

**And PHP:**

```
if($_POST['action']=='chkcard'){
    $firstSixChr = substr($_POST['cardNum'], 0, 6);
    $debit_or_credit = Salucro_payment::GetDebitOrCredit($firstSixChr);
    /*echo "<pre>";
    print_r($debit_or_credit);

     $debit_or_credit = $debit_or_credit[debit_or_credit];
    echo $card_type = $debit_or_credit[card_type];*/

    echo json_encode( $debit_or_credit );
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have u tried onblur event?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var xTriggered = 0;
$('#card_number').on('keyup',function(event) {
    var cardNum = $(this).val();
    if (cardNum.length == 6){
    var action = "chkcard";
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "/{$current_folder}/check_card_type.{$CONFIG.site.file.extension}",
        type: "post",
        data: { "cardNum" : cardNum, "action":action},
        success: function(debit_or_credit){
            var dataObj = JSON.parse(debit_or_credit);
            alert('This is a '+dataObj.debit_or_credit+' Card of '+dataObj.card_type+' type');

        },
        error: function(){
            alert('There is an error');
        }
    });
})
```

It uses `cardNum.length` to determine when to make the ajax call, whereas you were previously counting keypresses, which is a bad way to do it.

I also changed `live()` to `on()`.  Live was deprecated in jQuery v1.7.  `on()` is the method you should be using now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a character counter script and then apply AJAX when applicable. This is a perfect working example of character counter and input limiter

http://www.a100websolutions.in/character-counter-script-using-jquery/